# How to add 2 variables in Prolog rule statement?

Tags: prolog

This is the fact statement and rule :

```
%Fact statement
fare(asiawing,kch_brisbane,adult,330).
fare(asiawing,kch_brisbane,child,180).
fare(asiawing,kl_paris,adult,690).
fare(asiawing,kl_paris,child,550).

%Rule statement
totFareAsiaWing(T,D,C) :-
   fare(asiawing,D,C,F),
   T is F*1.45.

totAmountAsiaWing(Z,D) :-
   (  write('num of adult passenger :'),
      read(X),
      number(X),
      totFareAsiaWing(T,D,adult),
      Z1 is X*T
   ;  write('num of child passenger :'),
      read(Y),
      number(Y),
      totFareAsiaWing(T,D,child),
      Z2 is Z1+Y*T,
      write(Z2)
   ).
```

How to add `Z` for `X*T` and `Z` for `Y*T`? I tried to add it but it gives me

```
 ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Comment: I did it but it gives me ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated. -@lurker

Comment: All variables to the right of `is` must have a value or you will get that error. So you need to make sure `T`, `X`, and `Y` have values first.

Comment: So, does my code correct? I'm already fill the `X` and `Y` values. Same goes to `T`. But it keeps executing that error.

Comment: What line of code is your error referring to? Look at that line of code and make sure all of the variables in the arithmetic expression have a value.

Comment: I'm sorry I still can't fix it. Besides, I'm new to Prolog. Can you show me the way to fix this code?

Comment: You've really not given much information. What query did you run and what line of code is the error pertaining to? You don't have much spacing in your code, so I only just noticed you have a `;` (OR) which is lower precedence than `,`. Please explain what logic you want this to have (explain what it really is supposed to mean).

Comment: the query is `?- totAmountAsiaWing(Z,kl_paris).`. I want the answer to be like this. For example, `Z = 160`. The Z is the total adult and child fare.

Comment: Why do you have `;` in the logic? You want child AND adult, not child OR adult, right?

Comment: I changed it already. But it gives me `false`. I want to execute a value.

Comment: Your code has more than one problem. You should first try to write a minimal example where you see the same problem as the one you think you have at the moment, because now one cannot even figure out the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three fundamental problems in the code mentioned in the comments:

- A given variable cannot be reassigned (or reinstantiated) within a predicate clause without backtracking. In your case, you are trying to reassign `Z` (in your original code before it was edited based upon comment) and `T` (in your current code).
- The semicolon (`;`) represents disjunctive logic (an "OR") in Prolog, but doesn't make sense in the context of the logic of the problem in which you want a total fare for adults AND children
- You don't need to `write` the result, but make sure that `Z` is instantiated with the result.

For example, in your current code, you have:

```
...
totFareAsiaWing(T, D, adult),  % 'T' is instantiated with this call
...
totFareAsiaWing(T, D, child),  % Attempts to succeed with value of T from last call
...
```

The first call to `totFareAsiaWing/3` will instantiate `T` to a specific value. Then the next call will attempt to be true with that same specific value, which will fail. Thus, your answer comes back "no" or "false" when you attempt to do your query.

If you do a `trace`, you can observe what Prolog is doing:

```
| ?- trace.
The debugger will first creep -- showing everything (trace)

yes
{trace}
| ?- totAmountAsiaWing(Z,kl_paris).
      1    1  Call: totAmountAsiaWing(_17,kl_paris) ?
      2    2  Call: write('num of adult passenger :') ?
num of adult passenger :
      2    2  Exit: write('num of adult passenger :') ?
      3    2  Call: read(_109) ?
2.
      3    2  Exit: read(2) ?
      4    2  Call: number(2) ?
      4    2  Exit: number(2) ?
      5    2  Call: totFareAsiaWing(_159,kl_paris,adult) ?
      6    3  Call: fare(asiawing,kl_paris,adult,_185) ?
      6    3  Exit: fare(asiawing,kl_paris,adult,690) ?
      7    3  Call: _215 is 690*1.45 ?
      7    3  Exit: 1000.5 is 690*1.45 ?
      5    2  Exit: totFareAsiaWing(1000.5,kl_paris,adult) ?
      8    2  Call: _246 is 2*1000.5 ?
      8    2  Exit: 2001.0 is 2*1000.5 ?
      9    2  Call: write('num of child passenger :') ?
num of child passenger :
      9    2  Exit: write('num of child passenger :') ?
     10    2  Call: read(_296) ?
3.
     10    2  Exit: read(3) ?
     11    2  Call: number(3) ?
     11    2  Exit: number(3) ?
     12    2  Call: totFareAsiaWing(1000.5,kl_paris,child) ?
     13    3  Call: fare(asiawing,kl_paris,child,_372) ?
     13    3  Exit: fare(asiawing,kl_paris,child,550) ?
     14    3  Call: 1000.5 is 550*1.45 ?
     14    3  Fail: 1000.5 is 550*1.45 ?   % <<< FAILURE HERE! Statement not true
```

If you correct these problems, then your code will do what you want:

```
totAmountAsiaWing(Z,D) :-
    write('num of adult passenger :'),
    read(X),
    number(X),
    totFareAsiaWing(T1, D, adult),
    Z1 is X*T1,
    write('num of child passenger :'),
    read(Y),
    number(Y),
    totFareAsiaWing(T2, D, child),
    Z is Z1 + Y*T2.

| ?- totAmountAsiaWing(Z,kl_paris).
num of adult passenger :2.
num of child passenger :3.

Z = 4393.5 ? ;

no
| ?-
```

Comment: I see. The Z and T cannot be reassigned for this problem. So, I have to use another variable. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Rez for any prolog problem, you cannot reassign a variable within a predicate clause. It can only be reassigned or reinstantiated through backtracking.